# Is there a malicious code inside my wordpress site?

Tags: virus

Using my Iphone, I visited our website and when I click some of our Menu like Industry and Power instead of seeing the correct link I see Trk . tracksys55 . com then another websites which is somehow suspicious until it directed me to AppStore to download an app. What file should I check to verify or to remove this suspicious link. Thank you.

Comment: In short answer is yes. I am not sure how to get rid of it or what file it would be since all websites are set up differently. But to take further precautions I would change all passwords. This means your WordPress login, ftp login and if your hosting provider utilizes some sort of easy access dashboard ... I would change that password too.

Comment: @Nicole: changing passwords is not a complete solution.

Comment: @markratledge I know its not a complete solution but it is a start.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a malicious code inside my wordpress site?

Probably.

Carefully follow [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Change all passwords. Scan your own PC. Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting - WordPress Codex](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)